# Can't find error-Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In my ViewController, a user has the option to have an image as his/her background, stored in Parse. HOWEVER, when I delete this file, I get the following error - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I have an if statement nested within an if statement nested within an NSData fetch:

```
    // Load userBackground IF they have one. ELSE: keep it default
    let RPUserBackground = currentRPUser!["userBackground"] as? PFFile
        RPUserBackground!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // If there is NO ERROR (nil)

                // Set userProfilePicture
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    // If let statements hold an optional value
                    // IF imageData == imageData, set userProfilePicture
                    // THIS MEANS THAT THE OPTIONAL IS NOT NIL
                    self.RPUserBackground.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.RPDefaultView.hidden = true
                    self.RPUserBiography.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                }

            } else {
                // If there is an error, set default 
                    self.RPUserBackground.hidden = true
                    self.RPUserBiography.textColor = UIColor.grayColor() // GET RBG COLOR LATER
                    self.RPDefaultView.hidden = false

            }
        }
```

I don't know where this is coming from. I know that an if let statement returns an optional so I tried executing code to that relative if statement with an else. I don't know what's going on, please help me catch the error!

Comment: try to set breakpoint and figure out exactly which lines cause the error, then use `if let` or `guard let` there

Comment: Try printing all of the values to the console - also, check if `currentRPUser` or `RPUserBackground` is nil

Comment: @FuckShitUp Please as asked, give us console values to maybe see from where it can be coming from. Also, please specify us in which line you are getting the error.

Comment: I figured it out! All I had to do was add an if statement to the first let and make the else (the end of the new if let statement) handle the nil error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if let RPUserBackground = currentRPUser!["userBackground"] as? PFFile {
        RPUserBackground.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Set user's background Photo
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    /*
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    let size = CGSize(width: image!.size.width / 2, height: image!.size.height / 2)

                    self.RPUserProPic.image = image
                    self.RPUserProPic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                    */

                    self.RPUserBackground.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.RPDefaultView.hidden = true
                    self.RPUserBiography.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("User does not have a preferred background photo")
        self.RPUserBackground.hidden = true
        self.RPUserBiography.textColor = UIColor.grayColor() // GET RBG COLOR LATER
        self.RPDefaultView.hidden = false
    }
```